# How can a transpose buffer be realized in an FPGA

Tags: fpga, vhdl, signal-processing

As far as I understand a transpose buffer is where we write data of a nxn matrix as rows and then can read it out as columns of the same matrix. There does not seem to be an IP block to create such an entity. How can such a structure be realized usually? The objective is use in a 2D 8x8 DCT which is implemented as two 1D DCTs seperated by a transpose buffer.

Comment: If you have a better solution for the 2D DCT then I am open to that as well

Comment: Why do you think there is something special about this kind of buffer, rather than the logic that generates the addresses used to read & write it?

Comment: ... In other words, if the matrix dimensions are powers of two, the difference between the write addresses and the read addresses is a simple reordering of the address bits! Sometimes it's worth it to pad the matrix dimensions out to powers of two to take advantage of this fact. Otherwise, you need a couple of simple multipliers. What part of this do you not understand, so that we can construct an answer that will actually help you?

Comment: "Turning the Corner" involves a buffer address with a 8x8 block row component and 8x8 block column component and reordering those components in the aggregate address between the write address and read address. It can easily be implemented with two port memory or register files.

Comment: In BlockRam, which is usually dual ported.

Comment: I figured out how to make it last night before I slept. I wasn't sure where to start from but when it became obvious that it just needs a dual port RAM, the problem was solved.

Comment: @quantum231 Do you mind writing that answer here and accepting your own answer? I'd love to see it, regardless how simple it is.

Comment: Good idea, eventually I did not use the transpose buffer in the final version of design since I implemented the ISO-IEC 23002-2 MPEG 2D DCT of 8x8 matrix. I used shift registers to create to facilitate a "streaming interface". Anyway, I shall try to author an answer and print it here, I write notes on it in September, I shall have to find them.

Comment: @quantum231 You lieded.